# Google json style guide: How to send single item response?

Tags: json, openapi

There is an `items` node in the specifications which says it is for an array of items, like paging items, youtube video list

What if I have GET request on a single item, how should the response be formatted ?

Just to one item in the array? 
items:[item]

https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have `items` field for showing single item. If you're sure your API is always going to return single object, you can return it as `data` itself.

```
{
  "data": {
    "kind": "user",
    "fields": "author,id",
    "id": "bart",
    "author": "Bart"
  }
}
```

Fields such as `data.kind` `data.fields` `data.etag` `data.id` `data.lang` `data.updated` `data.deleted` can still be used here.

Source for snippet [docs](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=data.fields#data.fields)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think @tanmay_vijay's answer is correct or nuanced enough as it seems that single item responses are in arrays in the YouTube example in the docs.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2.0",
  "data": {
    "updated": "2010-02-04T19:29:54.001Z",
    "totalItems": 6741,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "itemsPerPage": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "BGODurRfVv4",
        "uploaded": "2009-11-17T20:10:06.000Z",
        "updated": "2010-02-04T06:25:57.000Z",
        "uploader": "docchat",
        "category": "Animals",
        "title": "From service dog to SURFice dog",
        "description": "Surf dog Ricochets inspirational video ...",
        "tags": [
          "Surf dog",
          "dog surfing",
          "dog",
          "golden retriever",
        ],
        "thumbnail": {
          "default": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BGODurRfVv4/default.jpg",
          "hqDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BGODurRfVv4/hqdefault.jpg"
        },
        "player": {
          "default": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGODurRfVv4&feature=youtube_gdata",
          "mobile": "https://m.youtube.com/details?v=BGODurRfVv4"
        },
        "content": {
          "1": "rtsp://v5.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQn-Vl-0uoNjBBMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
          "5": "https://www.youtube.com/v/BGODurRfVv4?f=videos&app=youtube_gdata",
          "6": "rtsp://v7.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQn-Vl-0uoNjBBMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
        },
        "duration": 315,
        "rating": 4.96,
        "ratingCount": 2043,
        "viewCount": 1781691,
        "favoriteCount": 3363,
        "commentCount": 1007,
        "commentsAllowed": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It could however be that it depends on the resource being targeted from the request. This is the way it is in the competing JSONAPI standard.

From JSONAPI standard:

> A logical collection of resources MUST be represented as an array, even if it only contains one item or is empty.

Comment: It's a mystery how it's supposed to work, but my impression (I have checked with two public implementations) is that for a single object, the `data` property will actually be the object itself. And any reserved properties on data (like `kind`) will simply be merged with the single object. Crazy if you ask me, but....